# class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings spring boot exclude issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, gradle, log4j2

Im trying to include log4j2 in my springboot project, but i get the following error.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/mn/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.10.0/8e4e0a30736175e31c7f714d95032c1734cfbdea/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/mn/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

My gradle file looks like this:

```
dependencies {                                                                      
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter') {                         
    exclude module:'spring-boot-starter-logging'                                    
  }                                                                                 
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')                       
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')                  
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2')                    
  compile('org.springframework:spring-oxm')                                         
  compile('org.codehaus.castor:castor-xml:1.3.3')                                   
  compile('org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1')                            

  testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')   
  testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')                  
}
```

Im pretty sure the Spring-boot-starter is the one implementing the logging, which is why i tried excluding that, but it doesnt work. Am i excluding it wrong, or the wrong thing?

Comment: For starters stop mixing Spring Boot versions, Spring versions and Spring Security versions. Spring Boot 1.5 doesn't work with Spring Security 5 (remove the version from `spring-security-test` this also applies to the `spring-boot-start-test`, spring-boot-starter-log4j2` and `spring-oxm` dependencies).

Comment: Do you want me to remove the versions from all of those, or just spring-security-test?

Comment: All of those, Spring Boot will manage the versions for you. You are currently mixing at least 2 spring versions (and probably 3) and different dependencies and managed dependencies.

Comment: edited the gradle file. Now where do i declare the actual version to use?

Comment: You don't as stated Spring Boot managed that for you, through the Spring Boot plugin.

Comment: I feel like just relying on latest versions all the time, is pretty bad, if changed are made that messes things up?
or is it this one?
buildscript {                        
  ext {                              
    springBootVersion = '2.0.0.RC1'  
  }

Comment: You don't rely on the latest version, the specified Spring Boot version manages the dependency versions. That's what M. Deinum mentioned. So only if you upgrade the Spring Boot version, it will upgrade also the other dependencies.

Comment: Okay cool. So my gradle file looks like this now. I still have the issue though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed this. It was cause because both spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-security also uses the standart logging, so it had to be excluded from all of them

Answer (score 4):

I used this

```
configurations {
    //eliminates logback
    all*.exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback'

    //eliminates StackOverflowError
    all*.exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: 'log4j-to-slf4j'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiple classes from spring-boot-starter use `spring-boot-starter-logging`:

- In my case both `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` and `spring-boot-starter-web`

You should exclude the dependecy using the `<exclusion>` tag, like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

also exclude from: spring-boot-starter-test,
for checking all dependencies, run:

```
 mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

If keycloak error with jboss logging, add config into active profile:

```
logging:
  provider: org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
```

If meet error below:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> com/lmax/disruptor/SequenceReportingEventHandler

Add dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
    <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```